# Should the new keyword be avoided in favour of another pattern (for example factory)?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI) from Google's clean code talks says `new` is bad for testing, which looks plausible at first sight.

What would be a good practice for PHP? Should I create a factory class to instantiate different object types with a method for each one, allowing loose coupling? Or would a generic initialization method (auto loader?) with a single method to init `new` instances be more suitable, although the latter has no return type specified, which leaves the code completion of an IDE in the dark.

Comment: That video is over 50 minutes long. Can you please summarize **why** they think the `new` keyword is bad?

Comment: TL;DR: tight coupling to a given class name and extremely hard to test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. The video is correct. Whenever you have `new` in a part of code, it makes it harder to test. Basically, there is no way to isolate the thing that you are testing from that class. Which means that you need to have a full coverage of that class (the one you had in your `new` statement), for your unit tests to actually be reliable.

The absolutely best option is to pass all the instances as dependencies (either in the class or the method), but usually that works only in some specific layer. For example, if written correctly, it is very simple to rid your controllers of any `new` statements. You just pass the services as dependencies in the constructor and pass either a `Request` abstraction or explicit values in the "action call".

So, passing in the dependencies (probably by using some DI container) is the best approach. And the one easiest to test. But this will not be universally available.

The rest of your code will probably end up (at least - in part) with some mix of `new` operators and factories.

You can mitigate the IDE related issue by both using the `::class`  in you factories and adding docblock comments:

```
/** @var \Mapper\SalesSomething\Invoice $invoice */
$invoice = $this->factory->create(Invoice::class);
```

My personal preferences are:

- controllers: related object only as dependencies via DIC
- services: factories for mappers, repositories as dependencies, domain entities with `new`
- mappers: only dependencies on the constructor
- entities: no dependencies
- views: related object only as dependencies via DIC
- presentation objects/widgets: via factories

But that's just my approach

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your insights. Adding the docblocks does the trick already for Eclipse.